# How can I get a copyright for my e-book?

Tags: legal, copyright

As I'm a new writer, I don't know how to get copyright for my first book. Could anyone help me please? My book is an e-book in E-Pub format.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Writers.  Copyright procedures vary by location; where do you live?

Comment: @MonicaCellio What do you mean by "Copyright procedures vary by location"? Can you
give an example not involving the USA?

Comment: @babou I said that because I don't want us to be US-centric, actually.  I know that in the US there's a place to register for a copyright, but that'll just apply to the US and (maybe?) other Berne Convention countries.  If I were in the UK or India or New Zealand I'd have no idea what to do, but it wouldn't involve the US copyright office.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Copyright procedures are essentially the same in all member countries
of the Berne Convention. What may vary is the way courts may evaluate
evidence. Registering with the copyright office (CO) may be with
little value against any strong evidence of earlier ownership by
another party or other technically strong proof. Anyone can steal work
and register. CO registration is just one many kinds of fairly strong
evidence. But the CO has another role as I explained in 2 other
places. (BTW, deletion may have been a wrong choice).

Comment: @babou while all Berne Convention signatories (and there are a lot of them) have the same *rules*, it seems possible that the *processes* are different.  If they're not -- if everybody pretty much handles the mechanics the same way -- then that's an important thing to cover in an answer.  (I don't know what you mean about deletion; there are no deleted answers on this question.)

Comment: One of the most basic rules of the Berne Convention is that you get
copyright without formalities: that means no process whatsoever. The
only issue is how you assert your copyright, which is a different
matter, related on how one can assert his rights in court or otherwise
for whatever matter. The need to register with the US CO depends on
how you wish to assert your right, and on where your work is first
published. This is explained in my answer (and partly in a plagiarized part
of the 2nd answer).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

WHERE? It differs from country to country.

In the US, you can register it with the [Copyright Office](http://www.copyright.gov/forms/). In other countries usually there's some counterpart to that.

Note - you already own copyright for your book. It happened the moment you saved the final form, automatically. Still, if you want your rights protected, you need *some* means of proving that you own copyright to that work - otherwise it's just your word against word of whoever plagiarized your work. There is a number of methods of proving you own the copyright, but registering your work with the copyright office is about the most reliable and simple.

Comment: Actually I'm in India. Could you please refer me the process of owning the copyright for my Book.

Comment: India is a signatory to the Berne Convention, which means that anything you publish in India is automatically protected by copyright in India and 166 other countries.  For information specific to India, you could check the Web site of its copyright office: http://copyright.gov.in

Comment: AFAIK, the USA is the only country where you need to register. This
is for historical reasons, as the USA joined the Berne Convention only
about 20 years ago. The Berne Convention is historically hostile to
formalities regarding effective ownership of copyright. The fact the
the USA were accepted as member despite the existence of this
registration process considerably weakened one major article of the
Berne Convention, with consequences that may reveal quite interesting. If any other country does have registration, I would be very interested in knowing it.

Comment: You are saying that getting a copyright "differs from country to
country". In what way does it differ? Can you give an example not
involving the USA?

Comment: @babou: Primarily, this is derived from local law. Berne Convention normalizes when copyright is in effect, but various countries handle various methods of proving so differently, e.g. the "mail a copy to yourself, don't open the envelope with dated mail stamp" is one that is currently no longer accepted in the US, while still acceptable in Poland. Also, for literary works you're normally supposed to go to a notary if not immediately publishing your work (then the Publisher handles that), while in the US you go to Copyright Office.

Comment: @babou: you don't need to register a work in the United states, although doing so does give you some additional punative fees you can ask the court to impose on an infringer.

Comment: @DougM You have to register work first published in the USA if you
want to sue. Publishing first in another country will save $35 if you
are not worried about being able to sue for statutory damages or attorney fees.

Comment: "You get a benefit if you register" is worlds apart from "you must register."  You can never register at all, and you still have copyright.

Comment: @DougM: Not registering leaves you almost defenseless against non-commercial violations (like net piracy). Sure you can never register, not even keep a recording with first creation date, and still have copyright, which will be completely useless (unenforceable) at that point.

Comment: @DougM I guess you were addressing my comment about historical reasons. I meant of course that you need to register for actual protection of copyright, rather than simple ownership. Comments are a bit too interactive, and cannot be corrected. But my posted answer was unambiguous on that. But I do not see why SF makes a difference between commercial and non-commercial. ( SF ) BTW, in other countries, when there is an office, it only plays the role of another public notary - nothing similar to the role of the US copyright office.

Comment: @babou: You can sue for specific damages corresponding to value of sales of the plagiarist in case of commercial use (which may exceed the costs of attorney fees etc by far). In case of non-commercial use you can sue for statutory damages, which are unlikely to cover the extra costs of the lawsuit which will appear if you didn't register.

Comment: You can sue commercial and non commercial infringers alike for the value of what they took (if it is a non-US work). If registered you can sue both for statutory damage.

Answer (score 3):

The important part here is that you always and already own the copyright to your work, at least in all 167 countries that have signed the [Berne Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention). There is nothing you need to do to own it. Even in the US, registration of a work with the Copyright Office is not a prerequisite for copyright protection, according to s[ection 408 of the U.S. Copyright Act of 1976](http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap4.html#408).

What you need to do is make sure you can *prove* that it is your work and, for questions of plagiarism, *when* you created it. That is the purpose of [copyright registration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_registration) in the US. It is also required in the US for some benefits, such as awards of statutory damages. Usually adequate proof is created when your work is published, e.g. by having your book printed by a publisher.

If your work remains unpublished and you are not in the US (and cannot register your work), you can deposit a copy of your work with a lawyer or notary.

---

Apart from the links provided in my answer, the [FAQ of the US Copyright Office](http://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/) provides a lot of useful information.

Comment: Dear God, NO.  The us mail is not a notary, and a postmark is little better than any other date on the paper.  You want to involve a second party, ideally someone like a notary or lawyer, but at least someone who can testify on your behalf.

Comment: @DougM I do not know the US case law on this postmark issue, and I
seriously doubt there is a Congress act about it (sorry, I am only
moderately familiar with US legalese). This is not a copyright matter
and law of evidence is relevant. Are you saying that a court will
never consider a postmark, or other time-stamps for registered mail
as evidence in a court case?  What about blood stains on a time
stamped envelope that would tell a murder occurred after a given date
(I realize that is criminal rather than civil issue).

Comment: "Registration of a work with the Copyright Office is not a
prerequisite for copyright protection". IMHO This is inaccurate, even
though it is in the law (probably as a matter of diplomacy when
joining the Berne Convention). It is true only for non US works and
some other specific cases. **There is copyright ownership and
copyright protection.** For unregistered US works, it is like owning a
house in a place where cops and judges will refuse to arrest or
sue trespassers. You own it, but it is not protected, and people can
freely infringe. Or is my legalese wrong?
Comments anyone ? cc @DougM

Comment: I read a comment by a lawyer who said that a self-mailed envelope with your work would serve as evidence in a court case. So while it may not decide a legal dispute in the same way as copyright registration does, it is still better than nothing, if you cannot afford the fees for registration or a notary. Also, why don't you just read the links I provided in my answer. The Wikipedia article on Copyright Registration even list different countries.

Comment: Since the OP is from India, why do we have to discuss the situation in the US at all ?!?

Comment: @Babou: I'm saying that a postmark is no better than just writing today's across the seal of an envelope.  It's not "nothing", but it's not as good as "hey bob, can you hold onto this copy of my novel for me?"

Comment: @DougM Possibly. It is up to the judge to assess the value of the
evidence produced. It may be that the postmark is not very reliable
...  but that depends on the postmark/envelope technology. I actually
intended to develop further my answer on this issue, in relation with
Berne 5.2, but given that I have been downvoted without explanation,
and that other users use my information to improve their answer
without event upvoting me, I think I will not take the trouble to say
more. Nothing against you. Thanks for pointing out my imprecision.

Comment: @babou: The analogy isn't completely right. You own a house (built it), but you don't have any deed to the house, and you failed to register the real estate. Someone's trespassing, you call the cops, they arrive and ask "Who is the the owner of the house who called us?" - the trespasser says "me", you say "me", and they shrug helplessly unable to discern which tells the truth.

Comment: @SF. I am not sure what is not completely right. My point is that, for US works, even if you have proof that it is your house/work and one million witnesses of the fact, and a hundred public notaries, you have nearly no protection against trespassers, i.e. copyright infringers, if you are not registered with the copyright office. This is not so for real houses. It is not a matter of cops shrugging, but of the judge shrugging (or nearly so), not helplessly, but because that is the law.

Comment: @SF. I am wondering why you made this comment. You are supposed to be the expert on this question.

Answer (score 1):

The ownership of the copyright is de facto attributed to the author as
he creates the work.

However, you may have to prove that you are the author against
possible claims by someone else. All means that can prove your
authorship are appropriate. You can register it with a public notary,
or you can publish an unforgeable signature ([SHA1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)) on the Internet and
manage to have it stored by the Internet archive. Or you can publish
that signature as a classified ad in a newspaper (some corporations
did that). What is important is to have a date officialised when you
were the only one (plus your trusted ones) to know the content of the
book.  Publishing may do that too, if you intend to go through a
professional publisher, which not everyone does any longer.

If your book is published in the USA first, you need to register it
with the  US copyright office if you want to be able to sue copyright
infringers in the USA ([article 411 of copyright law](http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap4.html#411)). You can register at any time, but it has to be before the infringement started if you seek statutory damages or attorney fees ([article 412 of copyright law](http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap4.html#412)). Registration does
not grant you the copyright (you already have it) but it grants the right to sue
to whoever owns the copyright (it can be sold).

However if you publish first in another country, you can sue copyright
violations in the USA without registering (as a consequence of the [Berne
Convention](http://www.wipo.int/treaties/en/ip/berne/trtdocs_wo001.html)). However, you cannot claim damage or attorney fees if you
had not registered before the infringement started.

Note that it is the country of first publication that matters, not the
nationality of the author, or the country where it was written, or the
language used. So, for an e-book, try to make it available in another country first, so that it is better protected in the USA, strange as it may seem. This works for US citizens too.

In all other countries (member of one of the major treaties on intellectual property), afaik, you can simply sue all copyright
violations, and with at least the same legal protections as local
citizens (even when they are subjects). There is no registration formality.

A last point is that copyright violation is not the same as
plagiarism. Copyright violation is duplicating your book without your
consent. Plagiarism is pretending to be the author of your book, or of
parts of your book.

Authorship is a moral right, independent from copyright. You can sell
your copyright, in whole or in parts. But authorship remains with the
author. It is protected by article 6bis of the Berne Convention. You can sue for plagiarism even when you do not own the copyright, but the specifics are country dependent.

*IANAL - this is no advice and I am not a lawyer  ... I probably do not even exist.*

Comment: Do you have a link to support your "you have to register before infringement or you cannot sue" claim?  I believe you're wrong as a matter of us law.

Comment: @DougM I have not been precise enough, but there are so many details. For a
US work, you must register in
order to sue ([article 411 of copyright law](http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap4.html#411)). But you cannot seek
statutory damages of attorney fees if you were not registered before
the infringement started ([article
412](http://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap4.html#412)). ...  Would you mind telling me what is wrong in my answer above.

Comment: nothing now.  looks perfect!